# Return SQL Assist-To-Turnover Ratio

Tags: sql

Access is telling me that the ROUND expression isn't part of the aggregate function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PlayerName, ROUND(g.A / g.TO,2) AS ATORatio
FROM (SELECT * FROM Players_t P INNER JOIN GameStats_t G ON P.JerseyNumber=G.JerseyNumber WHERE g.TO>0)
WHERE g.A/g.TO < (SELECT SUM(A)/SUM(TO) FROM GameStats_t)
GROUP BY PlayerName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query would help you.

Syntax of ROUND is `ROUND (VALUE, PRECISION)`
So, I have just added another paranthesis around (g.A / g.TO) in order to ensure that the syntax is maintained.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PlayerName, ROUND( (g.A / g.TO),2) AS ATORatio
FROM (SELECT * FROM Players_t P INNER JOIN GameStats_t G 
       ON P.JerseyNumber=G.JerseyNumber WHERE g.TO>0)
WHERE (g.A/g.TO) < (SELECT SUM(A)/SUM(TO) FROM GameStats_t)
GROUP BY PlayerName;
```